# How do I view a regex and containedin of a group?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm wanting to see how groups were created and what they are contained in.

What I'm doing now is this and then I search for the group.

```
:Verbose syntax
```

What I would like to do is this.

```
:verbose syntax SomeGroup
:echo SomeFunction('SomeGroup')
SomeGroup xxx match /\vsomeregex/ containedin=somewhere
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
redir => foo | silent syntax list SomeGroup | redir END
```